# AWS CodeBuild - copy yaml file to S3 after successful build

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I'm using CodeBuild to build Scala sbt project. during the build I'm doing the following steps.

- checkout code from Git.
- Install all sbt tools.
- Build code.
- Create Docker
- Publish docker file to AWS ECR
- Update K8s deployment file located in project root folder `deployment/deployment.yaml` with latest vesrion of published image using kustomize utility.
- Publish this file to AWS S3 bucket to run further deployment on AWS EKS.

Unfortunately, the last step fails and I can't move this deployment file to AWS S3 bucket.

```
artifacts:
  files:
    - deployment/deployment.yaml
  discard-paths: yes
  base-directory: 'deployment'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

```
base-directory: 'deployment'
```

... would mean that CodeBuild will look into 'deployment' directory for "deployment/deployment.yaml" which is probably wrong.

Try this:

```
artifacts:
  files:
    - deployment/deployment.yaml
  discard-paths: yes
```

One trick I have found useful is to install 'tree' in my buildspec and inspect the tree structure of directory to make sure I am specifying the correct path.

In Install Phase:

```
- apt-get install tree
```

Later in Buildspec:

```
- tree .
```